# Not getting past GetAwaiter().GetResult()

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, asp.net-4.5

I have a PostAsync method in an internal part of my code that doesn't seem to ever return a response. However, I use it synchronously via `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. The target framework is `net45`.

```cs
public async Task<TResponse> PostAsync<TResponse, TRequest>(string method, TRequest body)
{
    _logger.Log($"Method {method}, body {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body)} on url {_configuration.ApiUrl}");
    using (var customDelegatingHandler = new HMACDelegatingHandler(_configuration, _apiId))
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient(customDelegatingHandler))
        {
            var response = await client.PostAsync($"{_configuration.ApiUrl}/{method}",
                new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(content);
            }
            else
            {
                await Log(body, response);
            }
            return default;
        }
    }
}
```

What I do is call the PostAsync in another method:

```cs
public async Task<decimal> GetBalance(Request request)
{
    // = new MyCustomClient...

    QueryFundsResponse response = await customClient.PostAsync<Response, Request>("testAction", request);
    if (response == default)
        return 0.0m;

    return response.Amount;
}
```

Then, finally at the very top of the flow, I call the GetBalance method like this:

```cs
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
var balance = _provider
    .GetBalance(request)
    .ConfigureAwait(false)
    .GetAwaiter()
    .GetResult();
sw.Stop();
_logger.Log($"GetBalance -> method duration: { sw.ElapsedMilliseconds }");
```

I don't see the log in my logs at all, and I don't seem to ever get a response or any code executed after the `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. Switching the last block of code to be asynchronous and `await` the `GetBalance()` method is not really an option for me, sadly.

I am unable to figure out why nothing is changing, even after using the `.ConfigureAwait(false)` method.

Comment: This is a complex issue and the only thing that has any guarantees tied to it is rewriting to async code using async/await. Is this a high-traffic application? What kind of application? Web? Winforms? Console?

Comment: It is a web API in NET4.5. When someone logs in, a getbalance method is called, which internally (as per above) sends a request to a third party system here.

Comment: Web API actions can be `async`; why would you think switching to `async` and `await` is not an option?

Comment: Long story short, because in order to switch to async-await, we'd have to rewrite the whole system module, as it's closely tied to the database, where everything functions synchronously, because it's legacy code where DB sessions that are opened must remain synchronous.

Comment: Then rewrite the PostAsync to be Post and not use async code in there.

Comment: That would essentially mean HttpClient calls would be `HttpClient.PostAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, correct?

Comment: If HttpClient does not have any non-async methods you have to switch to WebClient I guess.

Comment: The whole code is in a shared library, and the same code is used for NET Standard and NET 4.5, and if I am not mistaken, WebClient isn't supported for NET Standard, nor is it recommended.

Comment: Well, the main problem is that you only have three options: 1. Hope for the best (this failed, you're already here), 2. Write everything async/await, or 3. Write nothing async/await. Option 4, mix and match is, unfortunately, option 1.

Comment: Can you separate the code so that the entire database code is run first in a synchronous manner, before you start dealing with the api's, so that you can complete everything that has to run on the main thread on the main thread, before you start with the async code that may end up switching to threadpool threads?

Comment: WebClient seems to be supported in .NET Standard 2.0 and 2.1 according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-6.0#applies-to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're experiencing [the common deadlock that happens when you block on asynchronous code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) (described in detail on my blog). There are a [variety of ways to get around it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development), but they're all hacks and none of them work in every situation.

In your case, I'd say either use the [direct blocking hack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development#the-blocking-hack) or use the [boolean argument hack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development#the-flag-argument-hack).

The direct blocking hack requires you to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere. Note that your current code *only* uses `ConfigureAwait(false)` where it *doesn't* do anything; `ConfigureAwait` configures the `await`, so it needs to go where the `await`s are. All of them.

The boolean argument hack means that your code will take a `bool` parameter that determines whether it executes synchronously or asynchronously. Note that `HttpClient` (for now) has an async-only API, so your custom delegating handler will need to support direct blocking, using `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Similarly, `Log` will either need a synchronous equivalent or also support direct blocking. Your code would end up looking something like this:

```
public Task<TResponse> PostAsync<TResponse, TRequest>(string method, TRequest body) => PostCoreAsync(method, body, sync: false);
public TResponse Post<TResponse, TRequest>(string method, TRequest body) => PostCoreAsync(method, body, sync: true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
private async Task<TResponse> PostCoreAsync<TResponse, TRequest>(string method, TRequest body, bool sync)
{
  _logger.Log($"Method {method}, body {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body)} on url {_configuration.ApiUrl}");
  using (var customDelegatingHandler = new HMACDelegatingHandler(_configuration, _apiId))
  {
    using (var client = new HttpClient(customDelegatingHandler))
    {
      var responseTask = client.PostAsync($"{_configuration.ApiUrl}/{method}",
         new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
      var response = sync ? responseTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult() : await responseTask;

      if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
      {
        var content = sync ? response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult() : await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(content);
      }
      else
      {
        var logTask = Log(body, response);
        if (sync)
          logTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        else
          await logTask;
      }
      return default;
    }
  }
}

public Task<decimal> GetBalanceAsync(Request request) => GetBalanceCoreAsync(request, sync: false);
public decimal GetBalance(Request request) => GetBalanceCoreAsync(request, sync: true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
private async Task<decimal> GetBalanceCoreAsync(Request request, bool sync)
{
    // = new MyCustomClient...

    QueryFundsResponse response = sync ?
        customClient.Post<Response, Request>("testAction", request) :
        await customClient.PostAsync<Response, Request>("testAction", request);
    if (response == default)
        return 0.0m;

    return response.Amount;
}

var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
var balance = _provider
    .GetBalance(request);
sw.Stop();
_logger.Log($"GetBalance -> method duration: { sw.ElapsedMilliseconds }");
```